# C++ Printing shared_ptr use count in tree

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm having trouble working out why when I Print a tree in different ways, I get different numbers of use_counts() for my shared pointers.

Using the code below, when I call the method "one->Print()", I seem to incorrectly get 2 refs for the immediate child of one, but when using "one->Print(one)" I get the correct number of refs, which is 1.

How could I change my code so that "one->Print()" returns the correct number of references for all nodes in the tree?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<class T> using sp = std::shared_ptr<T>;

struct Node {

    int value; 
    sp<Node> child;
    Node(int value): value {value} {}

    inline void Print() const {
        Print(std::make_shared<Node>(*this));
    }

    inline void Print(const sp<Node>& ptr) const {
        Print(ptr, "", false);
    }

    void Print(const sp<Node>& ptr, const std::string& prepend, bool isEnd) const {
        if(ptr != nullptr) {
            std::cout << prepend << (isEnd ? "└────" : "├────"); 
            std::cout << " " << ptr->value << " (" << ptr.use_count() << ")" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << " " << ptr->value << std::endl;
        }
        if(ptr->child != nullptr) {
            Print(ptr->child, prepend + (isEnd ? "     " : "│     "), false); 
        }
    }

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    sp<Node> one = std::make_shared<Node>(1);
    one->child = std::make_shared<Node>(2); 
    one->child->child = std::make_shared<Node>(3);
    one->child->child->child = std::make_shared<Node>(4);
    one->child->child->child = std::make_shared<Node>(5);

    one->Print(); 

    one->Print(one);

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like:

one->Print();

```
├──── 1 (1)
│     └──── 2 (2)
│          └──── 3 (1)
│               └──── 5 (1)
```

one->Print(one);

```
├──── 1 (1)
│     └──── 2 (1)
│          └──── 3 (1)
│               └──── 5 (1)
```

Comment: `std::make_shared<Node>(*this)` is usually wrong. you should use `shared_from_this` (although it does not make much difference in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because you use `std::make_shared<Node>(*this)` which create a copy of `*this` (`one`), which will copy `this->child` (`one->chile`) and increase the reference counter.

---

what you want is probably inherit from [`enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and use `shared_from_this`, then you will get

```
├──── 1 (2)
│     └──── 2 (1)
│          └──── 3 (1)
│               └──── 5 (1)
```

---

what's more, if you don't need the reference counter (usually true), you don't need a smart pointer if you're not going to manage the resource, you can simply accept a `Node*` . Actually, you can use `this` and drop all the pointers in this example.

---

the sample code. (use `this` instead of `ptr`)

```
struct Node: std::enable_shared_from_this<Node> {

    int value; 
    sp<Node> child;
    Node(int value): value {value} {}

    void Print() const {
        Print("", false);
    }

    void Print(const std::string& prepend, bool isEnd) const {
        std::cout << prepend << (isEnd ? "└────" : "├────"); 
        std::cout << " " << this->value << " (" << shared_from_this().use_count()-1 /*remove current count*/ << ")" << std::endl;
        if(this->child) {
            this->child->Print(prepend + (isEnd ? "     " : "│     "), false); 
        }
    }

};
```

---

You can also use `week_from_this` (c++17), [wandbox example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8IoMkuvNx5intfYQ)

Comment: Thanks, this seems promising. However, when I inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<Node>` and change `std::make_shared<Node>(*this)` to `shared_from_this()`, it now returns a `sp<const Node>`, which leads to conversion problem to `const sp<Node>&`. So, I changed the first argument of the other print functions to `const sp<const Node>& ptr`, but I then get the error `"cannot cast 'element_type' (aka 'Node') to its private base class 'const enable_shared_from_this<Node>'"`. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @user2520385 I cannot reproduce it in [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n2dwngNjC22gJyMV)

Comment: @user2520385 I'd recommend [this method](https://wandbox.org/permlink/N4IJZqzNa8sKwHrR), though (edited into answer)

Comment: @user2520385 [an example that gives my origin 2-1-1-1 result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dpiDWiu190xTedSe)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Print(ptr)`, it's passed as a reference to the shared pointer and no copy is made.

When you call `Print()`, it makes a copy of the shared pointer and passes that to `Print(ptr)`.

It's that copy that is upping the reference count. If you don't want that to happen, don't make a copy. You should be able to pass `this` directly as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, by calling `std::make_shared<Node>(*this)` you are actually invoking default copy constructor. Thus hitting somewhere `newObj->child = (*this).child` (i,e - the overloaded = (assignment operator) for the std::shared_ptr), thus increment the ref count to 2. When the function `Print()` exits, the shared_ptr is destroyed and thus reducing the ref count to 1.

When you are calling with reference, nothing is creating and thus you see the expected results.

One approach to solve this issue is to overload your function to accept `const Node &` and then you can use `*this`.